# How can i save choosen theme in LocalStorage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, darkmode

Items in localStorage are working just fine, adding, deleting and saving works as it should,  but if i choose dark theme and reload page, it will be light again, how can i fix it?

```
class TodoList extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {    
    super(props);     
    this.state = {    
      items: [],
      theme: 'theme' ? 'dark' : 'light'
    };
    this.switchTheme = this.switchTheme.bind(this); 
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this); 
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
  }
  switchTheme() {
    const theme = this.state.theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
    this.setState({ theme });
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
  }

  addItem(e) {
   ...
  }

  deleteItem(key) {  
   ...
  }

render() {
      return (
   ...
        <button className='button-switch' onClick = { this.switchTheme }>Switch theme</button>
    );
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      items: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')),
      theme: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theme'))
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(this.state.items));
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(this.state.theme));
  }
}
export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code, you are only updating the `data-theme` html attribute inside the `switchTheme` function:

```js
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
```

So in your example, you also need to set the attribute before the component mounts for the first time, inside your `componentWillMount`:

```js
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      items: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')),
      theme: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theme'))
    })

    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', this.state.theme);

  }
```

However, componentWillMount [is deprecated](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) and you shouldn't use it if possible.

Here is a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-breeze-evtsrs?file=/src/App.js) that removes the deprecated method and instead sets the theme from local storage inside the constructor.

See the `getInitialTheme` function called from the constructor when the component renders:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      theme: this.getInitialTheme()
    };

    this.switchTheme = this.switchTheme.bind(this);
  }

  // checks if local storage is available, and returns the value from it if so. if not, returns
  // a default of 'light'
  getInitialTheme() {
    try {
      const savedTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("theme")) || "light";
      // make sure we update the data-theme property with the localstorage value when the component
      // first renders
      document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", savedTheme);
      return savedTheme;
    } catch {
      // local storage is not available, e.g. the user is using incognito
      return "light";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, really useful and helped me with my problem :]